# Salvar os checkbox marcados e carrega-los quando a página for recarregada

Tags: javascript, html5, localstorage

gostaria que os checkbox que foram marcados sejam salvam e carregados sempre que a página seja recarregada ou aberta novamente, além disso, no lugar deles serão apresentados ícones referentes as opções.

Fiz uma função em java script que carrega as funções quando a página é aberta,utilizando o localStorage mas não está funcionando. Poderiam me ajudar por favor?

new.html

```
 <div class=" tab-pane active grid-container" id="biblio" align="center">

        <div id= "consulta0" class="toggle div-inline"  style="display:" > 
          <input type="checkbox" id="consultar-acervo" data-id="consultar-acervo"  name="toggle">
          <label for="consultar-acervo"></label>
          <p class= "nomeToogle"> Consultar Acervos</p>
        </div>

        <div id= "consulta1" class="toggle div-inline" style="display:" >
          <input type="checkbox" id="consultar-reserva" data-id="consultar-reserva" name="toggle"> 
          <label for="consultar-reserva"></label>
          <p class= "nomeToogle"> Consultar Reservas</p> 
        </div>

        <div id= "consulta2" class="toggle div-inline" style="display: ">
          <input type="checkbox" id="renovar-emprestimo" data-id="renovar-emprestimo" name="toggle">
          <label for="renovar-emprestimo"></label>
          <p class= "nomeToogle">Renovar Empréstimos</p> 
        </div>

        <!-- Icones de Biblioteca-->

          <div id = "zoom0" class="div-inline zoom" style="display:none">
          <a href="https://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=biblioteca&mode=compatibilidade&action=main:pesquisasimples" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Consultar Acervo" target=“_blank”>
            <img src="../images/biblioteca/consultar-acervo.png" style="width:40%" data-id="consultar-acervo" name="icons">
          </a>
          <p class= "nomeToogle"> Consultar Acervos</p>
        </div>

        <div id = "zoom1" class="div-inline zoom" style="display:none">
          <a href="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=biblioteca&mode=compatibilidade&action=main:resusuario" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Consultar Reserva" target=“_blank”>
            <img src="../images/biblioteca/consultar-reserva.png" style="width:40%" data-id="consultar-reserva" name="icons">
          </a>
          <p class= "nomeToogle"> Consultar Reservas</p>
        </div>

        <div id = "zoom2" class="div-inline zoom" style="display:none">
          <a href="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=biblioteca&mode=compatibilidade&action=main:renovusuario" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Renovar Empréstimo" target=“_blank”>
            <img src="../images/biblioteca/renovar-emprestimo.png" style="width:40%" data-id="renovar-emprestimo" name="icons">
          </a>
          <p class= "nomeToogle"> Renovar Empréstimo</p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

functions.js

```
        window.onload = function() { //executa o JavaScript imediatamente após a página ser carregada

    function checar(){

        var checa = document.getElementsByName("toggle");
        var img = document.getElementsByName("icons");


        var numElementos = checa.length;
        var i = 0;

        while (i <= numElementos){

            if(checa[i].checked == true){

                var dataCheckbox = checa[i].dataset.id;
                var dataImage = img[i].dataset.id;

                if (dataCheckbox[i] == dataImage[i]){

                   document.getElementById("zoom"+i).style.display = 'inline-block'; // mostra imagem
                   document.getElementById("consulta"+i).style.display = 'none'; // oculta checkbox marcada
                   document.getElementById("aplica").style.display = 'none'; // oculta botão aplicar
                   document.getElementById("edita").style.display = 'inline'; // mostra botão editar
                   document.getElementById("cancela").style.display = 'none'; // oculta botão cancela

                }

        //a partir daqui salva os checkbox marcados pelos usuários

        var opc = localStorage.getItem("checa[" + i + "]"); //verifica se há alguma opc no localStorage

        if (opc == null){
            break;
            }
        alert("deu");

        //grava as opc no localStorage
        localStorage.setItem("checa["+ indice +"]", checa);
        localStorage.setItem("img["+ indice +"]", img);
        indice++

            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("consulta"+i).style.display = 'none'; // oculta checkbox marcada
            }

            i++;
         }
    }

    document.getElementById('aplica').onclick = checar; 



            //função que carrega os ícones na tela de acordo com as opções salvas 
            var checa = document.getElementsByName("toggle");
            var img = document.getElementsByName("icons");
            var numElementos = checa.length;
            var b=0;

            for (i=0; i <= numElementos; i++){
                var opc = localStorage.getItem("checa[" + i +"]"); //verifica se há opc
                if(opc == null){
                    break;
                }

                var dataCheckbox = checa[i].dataset.id;
                var dataImage = img[i].dataset.id;

                if (dataCheckbox[i] == dataImage[i]){

                    document.getElementById("zoom"+i).style.display = 'none'; // oculta imagem
                    document.getElementById("consulta"+i).style.display = 'inline-block'; // mostra checkbox marcada
                    document.getElementById("aplica").style.display = 'block'; // mostra botão aplicar
                    document.getElementById("edita").style.display = 'none'; // oculta botão editar
                    document.getElementById("cancela").style.display = 'inline-block'; // mostra botão cancela

                }

                else{
                    document.getElementById("consulta"+i).style.display = 'inline-block'; // mostra checkbox marcada
                }


            }

};
```

Comment: Não crie um localStorage para cada item... crie apenas 1 e salve as opções em foma de string.

Comment: Obrigada pela sugestão, dvd, procurei a respeito aqui no fórum e acabei encontrado uma solução dada por vc em outro tópico. Tentei modificar para o meu contexto e add, na função checar(), só que ainda não funciona, olhe como ficou:

Comment: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");

   for(var itemCheck){
      item.addEventListener("click", function(){
         localStorage.consulta ?
            localStorage.consulta = localStorage.consulta.indexOf(this.id+",") == -1 
            ? localStorage.consulta+this.id+","
            : localStorage.consulta.replace(this.id+",","") :
         localStorage.consulta = this.id+","; 
      });
   }

Comment: if(localStorage.consulta){ for(var itemCheck){ 
         item.checked = localStorage.consulta.indexOf(item.id+",") != -1 ? true : false; }
   }  });

Comment: não, estou usando javascript. Com relação as imagens, é assim: depois que o usuário escolher os checkbox, eu verifico os que estão marcados e os substituo por ícones referentes as funcionalidades, os que não foram marcados tbm são ocultados da tela, mas não terão seus ícones mostrados. Essa função eu já fiz, só tentei utilizá-la para salvar esses checks escolhidos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode salvar os itens marcados no localStorage desta forma:

```
var ls = localStorage.getItem("box");
if(ls){
   var b = ls.split(",");
   for(var x=0; x<b.length; x++){
      document.getElementById(b[x]).checked = true;
      document.getElementById(b[x]).parentNode.style.display = "none";
      document.querySelector("[data-id='"+b[x]+"']").parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "block";
   }
   var checados = b;
}else{
   var checados = [];
}

var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("#biblio div [type='checkbox']");
for(var x=0; x<boxes.length; x++){
   boxes[x].onchange = function(){
      var idx = checados.indexOf(this.id);
      if(this.checked && !~idx){
         checados.push(this.id);
         document.getElementById(this.id).parentNode.style.display = "none";
         document.querySelector("[data-id='"+this.id+"']").parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "block";
      }else{
         checados.splice(idx, 1);
      }
      localStorage.setItem("box", checados);
   }
}
```

Ao recarregar a página, os checkboxes continuarão marcados.

Retire os `data-id` dos checkboxes que não são desnecessários já que o `id` tem o mesmo valor.

Comment: Só me explique, por favor, o que essas linhas que vc add estão executando, acho que não entendi o // document.querySelector("[data-id='"+this.id+"']").parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "block";

Comment: `document.querySelector("[data-id='"+this.id+"']").parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "block"` seleciona o avô do elemento que tem o data-id igual ao id e seta display block... o `parentNode` seleciona o pai, se eu colocar 2x, seleciona o avô.

Comment: Dvd, poderia me tirar outra dúvida? Percebi que a página carrega a partir dessa linha de código var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("#abas div [type='checkbox']"); assim, eu tentei fazer que, quando a página for recarregada ele pegue os checks marcados, que estão salvos no localStorage compara se existe alguma imagem com o mesmo data-id, se estiver mostra na tela apenas essas imagens e oculta os outros que não estão marcados. Por exemplo tenho as imagens 1 2 3 e os checks 1 2 3, se eu escolher os checks 1 e 2, quando eu abrir a página novamente gostaria que aparecesse as imagens 1 e 2.

Comment: boxes[x].onchange = function(){ 
      var idx = checados.indexOf(this.id);
      if(this.checked && !~idx){ 
         checados.push(this.id);

      }else{
         checados.splice(idx, 1);
         var img = document.getElementsByName("icons");

         if(this.id == img[x].dataset.id){// comparo se o id do checkbox marcado é igual da imagem, se for
            document.getElementById("zoom"+x).style.display = 'inline-block'; // mostra imagem
         }else{
          document.getElementById("zoom"+x).style.display = 'none'; // mostra imagem
         }
      }

Comment: Eu fiz isso na resposta, não?

Comment: não, ele está desativando o check qdo eu desmarco ele, e qdo recarrego aparece todos

Comment: Mas as imagens já não carregam ocultas? Neste trecho `document.querySelector("[data-id='"+b[x]+"']").parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "block";` eu mostro apenas as que estão no LS.

Comment: aqui não funcionou... :/

Comment: Vc retirou os data-id desses inputs? `<input type="checkbox" id="consultar-acervo" data-id="consultar-acervo"  name="toggle">`

Comment: Não, só add o código no meu arquivo js

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79455/discussion-between-dvd-and-mstos).